# How to clear input field after hitting submit

Tags: javascript

I have a form, and I would like to clear the input field every time I enter the submit (plus) button.

I have tried using this, it does not work. I may be implementing it in the wrong spot.

```
document.getElementById('add-item').value='';
```

My Javascript code is below.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    // Add event listeners
    document.getElementById('add-item').addEventListener('click', addItem, false);
    document.querySelector('.todo-list').addEventListener('click', toggleCompleted, false);
    document.querySelector('.todo-list').addEventListener('click', removeItem, false);

    function toggleCompleted(event) {
        console.log('=' + event.target.className);
        if(event.target.className.indexOf('todo-item') < 0) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(event.target.className.indexOf('completed'));
        if(event.target.className.indexOf('completed') > -1) {
            console.log(' ' + event.target.className);
            event.target.className = event.target.className.replace(' completed', '');
            document.getElementById('add-item').value='';
        } else {
            console.log('-' + event.target.className);
            event.target.className += ' completed';         

        }
    }

    function addItem() {
        var list = document.querySelector('ul.todo-list');
        var newItem = document.getElementById('new-item-text').value;
        var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
        newListItem.className = 'todo-item';
        newListItem.innerHTML = newItem + '<span class="remove"></span>';
        list.insertBefore(newListItem, document.querySelector('.todo-new'));
    }

    function removeItem(event) {
        if(event.target.className.indexOf('remove') < 0) {
            return;
        }
        var el = event.target.parentNode;
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }

});
```

Comment: do you only wanted to clear the element with 'add-item' id ?

Comment: @JF-Mechs yes, I want to remove the input field where you can add the item.

Comment: Add autocomplete="off" to your form tag may also be useful

Answer (score 1):

Use form reset method to clear inputs in one go.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
document.getElementById('new-item-text').value = "";
```

regarding your need, you will need to put it at the end of your addItem()

you can refer this simple code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="test">
        <button onclick="func()">remove</button>
        <br/>
        Value = <span id="val"></span>
        <script>
            function func(){
                alert("clicked");
                document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = document.getElementById('test').value;
                document.getElementById('test').value = '';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your textbox value = '' in submit button.
and you can create a ClearFunction and then you can call it everytime you need it.

```
function cleartextbox() {
    $('#name').val("").focus();
    $('#selectgender').val("");
    $('#telephone').val("");
}
```